# Retrofit post request with JsonObjectField

Tags: android, retrofit

I need send post requests like this:

```
{
  "request": "AppStart",
  "appKey": "d7ea9ac1-8eb0-44f8-809d-bff6944db6c7",
  "param" : {
    "somedata" : "data"
  },
  "buildId": "111111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111"
}
```

I write simple function for register appllication:

```
 public interface RestClient {
        @Headers("Content-Type: application/json" )
        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/")
        <T> void callMethod(
                @Field("request") String method,
                @Field("appKey") String key,
                @Field("param") JsonObject params,
        );

 public void registerUser(String key, string userID) {
       JsonObject params = new JsonObject().putProperty("userId" userID);
       api.callMethod("registerUser", key, params);
 }
```

this is retrofit log:

> request=registerUser&appKey=123bff6944db6c7&param=%7B%22deviceUdid%22%3A%2276839a55470a2cd4%22%7D

How to fix my code?

Answer (score 0):

In your `registerUser` method build an object that reflects the desired JSON structure and then use Retrofit's `@Body` annotation.

```
public void registerUser(String key, string userID) {
    CallMethodBody callMethodBody = ...
    api.callMethod(callMethodBody);
}

public interface RestClient {

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json" )
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/")
    <T> void callMethod(@Body CallMethodBody callMethodBody);
}
```

That will send the whole JSON string as the body of your POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@Field` you should use `@Body`.

> **Request Body**
>
> An object can be specified for use as an HTTP request body with the
>   @Body annotation.
>
> ```
> @POST("/users/new") 
> void createUser(@Body User user, Callback<User> cb);
> ```
>
> The object will also be converted using the RestAdapter's converter.

Reference: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

---

You need to create class which will represent your request body, e.g.:

```
public class Data {
    String request;
    String appKey;
    String buildId;

    Param param;
}

public class Param {
    String somedata;
}
```

Next you can use this class as request body:

```
public interface RestClient {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/")
    <T> void callMethod(@Body Data data);

    public void registerUser(Data data) {
        api.callMethod(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: if I have 200 methods, I need to create 200 very simple classes for Params. Is there better way?

Comment: Instead of `String` you can use `Map` in `Param` class - this eliminates the need to create "200 very simple classes".